# How to remove empty tags in rich text? (Redactor or Twig)

Tags: templating, redactor

What is the preferred method to remove an empty tag from the content of a rich text element?

Example result:

```
<p>
  Lorem<a href="…"></a> ipsum
</p>
```

When editing text in the WYSIWYG editor (Redactor) the result can contain empty anchor tags. This is a problem when navigating the page with the tab key, for instance, because the user can not see the focus anymore.

How can I automatically remove those artefacts?

Comment: one way is to allow HTML in the redactor config and check it over for these things, but that's not great or automatic. You could do something like *:empty{display:none} in the css but that's not great either (as a workmate of mine said, that's just sweeping the turd under the rug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using this solution:

#### Filter empty tags in Craft/Twig template

```
{{ entry.houseDescription|replace('/<[^\\/>][^>]*><\\/[^>]+>/', '')|raw }}
```

1. The [`replace`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) filter `/<[^\\/>][^>]*><\\/[^>]+>/` searches for empty tags and removes them.
2. The [`raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) filter stops Twig from escaping HTML tags.

[Regular expression test (RegExr)](http://regexr.com/3f3dp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - by hand is the only way I've found!

Comment: Thx, your are right. I posted my "by hand" solution as answer.